# Approach for system testing using maven, cargo, jetty and HSQL

Tags: maven, selenium, jetty, war, cargo

I have been trying to get some Selenium system test cases to run during the integration-test phase. I want Cargo to deploy the WAR to a local Jetty installation. Then I want my test cases to run, using test versions of Spring configuration files. The goal is to run tests against the web application mocking out all external dependencies, and using HSQL as the database.

I think this approach is wrong: I think during this phase the WAR file that is created is a "production WAR", it doesn't include the test resources. What is the best way of doing this? Create a new profile in the POM which builds a "test version" of the WAR during the "test" phases? Are there any examples showing how to do this? Should I be taking a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different approach. The problem with testing with the "test resources" is that you are not testing your real application. There could be a lot of "code" that matters in your resources, specially if you are using Spring. 
I would test the "production WAR" with a special configuration for your tests. Every external systems (database, external WebServices, etc.) should be configurable (using JNDI, an external configuration file, etc.) and not hard coded in your WAR.

The following maven configurations should do the work:

1. Using [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) and the exec:exec plugin, you can start HSQLDB.
2. The database can be initialized (schema and tables creation, data inserts) using [sql-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/sql-maven-plugin/).
3. Then you can use Cargo to start your WAR in a Jetty instance.
4. Using the maven-failsafe-plugin, you can start your JUnit tests which use Selenium.

Of course, you also need to start a mock version of all your other external systems.